# Why not declaring the variable during initialization gives different output in c++

Tags: c++

When I was recently practicing on hackerearth, I found an interesting issue while solving this problem: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/magical-tree/

I solved it using C++.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int l;
cin>>l;
int lInitial=l;
int max;
while(l--)
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int v1=((int)s[0]-48),v2=0;
    for(int i=1;i<s.length()-1;)
    {
        v2=(int)s[i+1]-48;
        if(s[i]=='-')
            v2=-1*v2;
        v1=v1+v2;
        i=i+2;
    }
    if(l==lInitial)
        max=v1;
    else
        max=v1>max? v1 : max;
}
cout<<max<<endl;
}
```

For the given input:

```
4 
8-6+2+4+3-6+1 
1+1+1+1 
2+3+6+8-9 
2+7+1-6
```

Output was : 4197440

As soon as I declared max to zero during initialization

```
int max=0;
```

I got the desired output which is : 10

Can someone explain why this inconsistency exists even when I ensured that during first while loop execution variable max will take the first case value v1 as shown below.

```
if(l==lInitial)
        max=v1;
    else
        max=v1>max? v1 : max;
```

I used the code editor provided on their website. The language selected was C++(g++ 5.4.0)
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you inspect your code line by line with the debugger to check what's going on?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but try to avoid using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) like e.g. `48` for the [ASCII encoded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) character `'0'`. Use the (portable) character literal `'0'`.

Comment: The first time `if(l==lInitial)` is executed `l` has already been decremented at the top of the `while` loop.  Hence `max=v1;` is *never* executed.  As stated by @user0042, you should use a debugger.

Comment: As for your problem, uninitialized variables will have an *indeterminate* value, and using those, even just reading their seemingly random value, leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. That way I don't have to check ASCII sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Because in this bit:

```
if(l==lInitial)
        max=v1;
    else
        max=v1>max? v1 : max;
```

If `l` is not equal to `lInitial`, it will execute this line:

```
max=v1>max? v1 : max;
```

The problem here is that you're comparing `v1` against `max`, which hasn't been initialised yet. So it's random chance if that will be true or not. If it is true, it will set `max=v1`. However, if it's not, it will set `max=max`. So it will stay at the same uninitialised value it had previously.

There's a very good chance that the unitilaised value will be much higher than any of the values in your input, and therefore it will always take whatever value it is.

Comment: So you are saying l=lInitial - 1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `while(l--)` uses the old value of `l` to decide whether to continue looping, it then decrements `l` before entering the loop. Thus the first time through the loop, `l` will be `lInitial - 1` and you won't trigger the initialization branch of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `l--` copies the value of `l`, decrements `l` and returns the copied value. Before the first loop, the value of `l` is equal to `lInitial`. Upon entering the first loop, the statement `l--` is executed, hence during the first loop `l`'s value is equal to `lInitial-1`. Therefore in the first loop the condition `l==lInitial` is false.

One way to fix your code is to change lInitial's initialization to `int lInitial=l-1;`. However, this would make your code 'ugly'   since `lInitial` now doesn't actually contain initial value of `l`.

Another way is by changing the if condition `l==lInitial` to `l==lInitial-1`.